# Is there a method where once the numbers are converted with commas, can the number be kept as integer?

Tags: python-3.6

The comma separated value is a string and I want to keep the property as a integer itself for calculations like in Excel.

```py
num = f"{1000:,d}"
'1,000'
```

I wanted the output 1,000 but as a integer type.

Comment: The value `1,000` should be the result of some presentation logic; integers don't have commas (or decimal components).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. But in Excel, there is an option to format the number. What it does is, the values are displayed as comma separated but the type is integer itself.